# AngularJS $http loading screen compatibility

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I've used the following angular module to create a loading screen until all $http requests finish.  It works fine on angular 1.0.7, but doesn't work on angular 1.2.10 . I need to use angular-resource, and angular-route also, so I can't stay on angular 1.0.7.  Can anyone help me rewrite this to work on the latest angular?

```
angular
.module('loadingOnAJAX', [])
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    var numLoadings = 0;
    var loadingScreen = $('<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:10000;background-color:gray;background-color:rgba(70,70,70,0.2);"><img style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;" alt="" src="loading.gif" /></div>')
        .appendTo($('body')).hide();

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(function() {
        return function(promise) {
            numLoadings++;
            loadingScreen.show();
            var hide = function(r) {
                if (!(--numLoadings)){
                    loadingScreen.hide();
                }
                return r;
            };
            return promise.then(hide, hide);
        };
    });
});
```

In angular 1.2.10, the loading screen doesn't appear, but If I place an alert() inside the hide function, the loading screen appears until I press OK on the alert.  So I'm not sure if things are happening too fast, or what.

***Corrected Version:***

```
angular
.module('loadingOnAJAX', [])
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    var numLoadings = 0;
    var loadingScreen = $('<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:10000;background-color:gray;background-color:rgba(70,70,70,0.2);"><img style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;" alt="" src="loading.gif" /></div>')
        .appendTo($('body')).hide();

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            'request': function(config){
                numLoadings++;
                loadingScreen.show();
                return config;
            },
            'response': function(response){
                if (!(--numLoadings)){
                    loadingScreen.hide();
                }
                return response;
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: This version of an interceptor is deprecated. See [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized this in the first place! I've posted my  new working version above, using the information at the doc link you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at angular_busy [here](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy). Its pretty easy to implement.

Note that on the page you also find a link to  Andy Joslin's excellent angular-promise-tracker. Which should be the base for your own experiments.[Here](https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker)

Answer (score 0):

```
angular
.module('loadingOnAJAX', [])
.config(function($httpProvider) {
var numLoadings = 0;
var loadingScreen = $('<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:10000;background-color:gray;background-color:rgba(70,70,70,0.2);"><img style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;" alt="" src="loading.gif" /></div>')
    .appendTo($('body')).hide();

$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
        'request': function(config){
            numLoadings++;
            loadingScreen.show();
            return config;
        },
        'response': function(response){
            if (!(--numLoadings)){
                loadingScreen.hide();
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
});
});
```